# Problems adding rules.d rule for unit with multiple tty devices

Tags: ubuntu, udev

I want to add a rule under `/etc/udev/rules.d` for a Texas Instruments CC1352P-2 development board. On my Ubuntu server it creates two ttyACM devices:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 1 Sep 28 10:37 /dev/ttyACM1
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 166, 2 Sep 28 07:28 /dev/ttyACM2
```

And I want to create a symlink to the first device (`ttyACM1` in this case). But when using `usb-devices` it creates only one section for the board, with one set of vendor ID + product ID:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0451 ProdID=bef3 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Texas Instruments
S:  Product=XDS110 (03.00.00.15) Embed with CMSIS-DAP
S:  SerialNumber=L430037Y
C:  #Ifs= 7 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#=0x0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=02 Prot=01 Driver=cdc_acm
I:  If#=0x1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_acm
I:  If#=0x2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
I:  If#=0x3 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=02(commc) Sub=02 Prot=01 Driver=cdc_acm
I:  If#=0x4 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=0a(data ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=cdc_acm
I:  If#=0x5 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=usbhid
I:  If#=0x6 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

I've then used those ID's to create a rule in `/etc/udev/rules.d/50-devboards.rules`:

```
# Texas Instruments CC1352P-2 development kit
KERNEL=="ttyACM*" ATTRS{idVendor}=="0451", ATTRS{idProduct}=="bef3", MODE="0666", SYMLINK+="tty-CC1352P-2"
```

This ends up creating a symlink to `ttyACM2`, not `ttyACM1`.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Sep 28 07:28 /dev/tty-CC1352P-2 -> ttyACM2
```

Question: How can I target a rule to a specific tty device if a unit creates multiple tty devices under `/dev`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between "tty device" and "USB device" you have an intermediate layer – "USB **interface**". The driver doesn't attach to the USB device as a whole, but each interface has a separate instance of some driver (potentially different drivers).

*(Unfortunately Ubuntu does not include usbutils' [lsusb.py](https://github.com/gregkh/usbutils/blob/master/lsusb.py.in), with the `-i` option it will display the full USB hierarchy including interfaces.)*

Your USB device has several interfaces numbered 0x00 to 0x06, and likely ttyACM1 is created over interface 0 while ttyACM2 is over interface 3 (but you can use `udevadm info /dev/ttyACM2` to find out).

Use the interface number as part of your match, e.g. `ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"`.

---

However, all ATTRS (and ENVS) matches in a single rule latch onto the same "parent" level while you need to match attributes from two different levels. So you might need to use ENVS and/or have two rules:

1. In first rule, match the "interface" device and apply an ENV property:

   ```
   ACTION!="remove", DEVTYPE=="usb_interface", \
     ATTRS{idVendor}=="xx", ATTRS{idProduct}=="xx", \
     ATTR{bInterfaceNumber}=="xx",
     ENV{devboard_link}="tty-CC1352P-2"
   ```
2. Then match the "tty" device and check whether the parent has that property:

   ```
   ACTION!="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="tty", \
     ENVS{devboard_link}=="?*",
     IMPORT{parent}="devboard_link",
     TAG+="uaccess", SYMLINK+="$env{devboard_link}"
   ```

(Examples untested.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Got it working by following your tips.